# Выбор учебника по C#

Tags: c#, книги

День добрый, господа!
Решил начать изучать С#, имею базовые понятия о переменной, о функции, и что такое цикл.
Какую книгу посоветуете? Их очень много, и не знаю какую выбрать.
Спасибо!

**Обновление**

Какой из этих?

1. Язык программирования C# 2010 и платформа .NET 4 - Эндрю Троелсен
2. C# 4.0 и платформа .NET 4 для профессионалов - Кристиан Нейгел
3. CLR via C#. Программирование на платформе Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 на языке C# - Джеффри Рихтер
4. C#. Программирование для профессионалов - Джон Скит
5. C# 4.0. Полное руководство – Герберт Шилдт

Comment: MSDN же.  .

Answer (score 7):

Я бы посоветовал почитать Албахари "C# x.0 in a Nutshell" (возьмите самый свежий вариант), Джона Скита "C# in Depth" (очень рекомендую!). Джеффри Рихтер крут, но наверное лучше его читать попозже.

Советуют Билла Вагнера, но я сам не читал.

Очень очень не советую Шилдта: его книги -- просто источник неверных советов, фактических ошибок и зияющих дыр. Если вы хорошо владеете английским, поищите в гугле "bullschildt", вы будете удивлены тем, как много людей ненавидят этого автора.

---

Ваш список я бы оценил так:

- Язык программирования C# 2010 и платформа .NET 4 - Эндрю Троелсен: нормально
- C# 4.0 и платформа .NET 4 для профессионалов - Кристиан Нейгел: не знаю
- CLR via C#. Программирование на платформе Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 на языке C# - Джеффри Рихтер: отлично, не для первого чтения
- C#. Программирование для профессионалов - Джон Скит: отлично, срочно читать
- C# 4.0. Полное руководство – Герберт Шилдт: а у вас ещё принимают макулатуру?

Comment: Неужели кто-то также не любит Шилдта, как я

Comment: @rasmisha: если верить гуглу, пол-интернета :)

Comment: Яростно плюсую. Половина интернета везде советует Шилдта, остальная половина его ругает.

Answer (score 1):

Из перечисленного однозначно могу рекомендовать Троелсена и Шилдта. Обе книги довольно объемные, но целиком их читать вам пока не обязательно - прочтите хотя бы половину, хорошо разобравшись в материале. А потом и до остального доберетесь, когда наберетесь достаточно опыта и базовых знаний.
Нейгела, Рихтера и Скита даже не трогайте - с вашими познаниями читать эти книги очень рано.

Answer (score 1):

Я вот читал книги по мере написания кода. Чтобы понимать базу работы кода читал Рихтера, многие вещи читал у Ватсона (по мне неплохо объясняет).

Ватсон, Скит, Троелсен заслуживают внимания.

Answer (score 1):

Pro C# 5.0 and the .NET 4.5 Framework -> C# 5.0 in a Nutshell -> CLR via C# -> книги по технологиям (ASP.NET, WPF, WCF, etc)

рекомендую издательство Apress, книги серии Pro неплохи, страниц много конечно, но читать уже можно не все, а избранные главы

Answer (score -1):

Вот [книжка](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxGx2-4UEd-VWi0weUFTSUVjelE)
Шилдт Г. -  C# 4.0 полное руководство - 2011
Думаю это самый нормальный вариант.

Comment: Спасибо, но полистав эти книги почему-то больше всех понравился Троелсен. Послушаю что скажут о ней, и о других книгах. Но Спасибо!

Comment: Троелсена для начала однозначно, потом Шилдта, чтобы закрепить материал! Потом WPF, WCF - отдельными книгами, разумеется. И в космос, покорять! =)

Comment: Опять Шилдт. Это уже не смешно.

Answer (score -1):

Очень круты братья Албахари, однако переводных лучше даже не пытаться читать, кроме как для лулзов: одна "объектная ориентация" чего стоит.

Пытался читать Шилдта, - он реально местами расстраивает и дает вредные советы. Мне хватило главы про исключения, где он восторженно ликуя объясняет, как круто взять все и завернуть в трайкетчи, отлавливая эксепшны, вместо нормальной, но муторной с его точки зрения, проверки через if. Однако, сей замечательный человек ни разу не указывает, что трайкетчи == жуткие тормоза, особенное, если много чего вложено. А уж за описаный им отлов любого эксепшна во внешнем кетче вообще надо у разработчика отрывать ноги и пришивать на то место, откуда они растут руки.

Comment: Не стоит отвечать на старые вопросы-опросники